# How to express normalisation where rows sum to 1 for multiple rows?

Tags: notation

I have a list of lists. I want to divide every value in each list by the sum of that list.

What I did is: a list of lists `S`, where each list in `S` is [image]. Each value in [image] is [image]. I wrote the normalisation down as:

[image]

This does not seem right to me, but I don't know how to correct it. How can I correctly express this?

LaTeX:

```
\begin{equation}
S_k^i = \frac{S_k^i}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^K S_k^i} \qquad \forall S_k^i
\end{equation}
```

Comment: @Macavity Good idea about the hat. If the rest is actually correct you can post your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K$ is the number of elements in each list I presume.

I would suggest a new variable, say $\hat{S_k^i}$ to represent the normalised lists and elements in the LHS, but the RHS looks good.

Comment: Forgot to ask in my comment, what does RHS and LHS mean?

Comment: Usually refer to Left Hand Side (LHS) and Right Hand Side (RHS) of equations, inequalities etc.